# Converts list of dates to json list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, date

I have below code which make a list of date between start and end date with a frequency of 13 days. I'm not sure how I can make it a list with start and end date on it(as what is shown in my expected output)

Note: I should also added those remaining dates

**Python Code**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

start_date = '2021-10-01T17:30:00Z'
end_date = '2021-10-30T21:00:00Z'

pd.date_range(start_date, end_date ,freq='13D')
```

**Output:**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-10-01 17:30:00+00:00', '2021-10-14 17:30:00+00:00','2021-10-27 17:30:00+00:00'],
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
{
"start_date": "2021-10-01 17:30:00+00:00",
"end_date":"2021-10-14 17:30:00+00:00"
},
{
"start_date": "2021-10-14 17:30:00+00:00",
"end_date":"2021-10-27 17:30:00+00:00"
},
{
"start_date": "2021-10-27 17:30:00+00:00",
"end_date":"2021-10-30 17:30:00+00:00"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use comprehensions to solve this problem (I'm assuming you might want to extend this to more than 3 dates in the future, otherwise you could just write out the expected output by hand and be done with it):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

start_date = '2021-10-01T17:30:00Z'
end_date = '2021-10-30T21:00:00Z'
date_range = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='13D')

intervals = [{
    "start_date": str(date_range[i]),
    "end_date": str(date_range[i + 1])
} for i in range(len(date_range) - 1)]

if intervals and pd.Timestamp(end_date) != intervals[-1]["end_date"]:
    intervals.append({
        "start_date": intervals[-1]["end_date"],
        "end_date": end_date
    })
print(intervals)
```

Comment: Oh, I tried this and it returned empty when I adjusted the end date to 2021-11-30

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the behavior you've stated with my code snippet. Try copying it and tell me if anything changes.

Comment: I actually updated the expected output.. It supposed to have 13 days per start and end date and then just get the remaining dates

Comment: Edited. Please make sure your expected output is correct in the future -- it prevents answerers from giving effective solutions in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [382]: x = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date ,freq='13D')
In [389]: l = []
In [393]: for ix, ele in enumerate(x):
     ...:     if ix + 1 < len(x):
     ...:         d = {"start_date": str(ele), "end_date": str(x[ix + 1])}
     ...:         l.append(d)
     ...: 

In [400]: if l[-1]['end_date'] < end_date:
     ...:     l.append({'start_date': l[-1]['end_date'], 'end_date':end_date})
     ...: 

In [401]: l
Out[401]: 
[{'start_date': '2021-10-01 17:30:00+00:00',
  'end_date': '2021-10-14 17:30:00+00:00'},
 {'start_date': '2021-10-14 17:30:00+00:00',
  'end_date': '2021-10-27 17:30:00+00:00'},
 {'start_date': '2021-10-27 17:30:00+00:00',
  'end_date': '2021-10-30T21:00:00Z'}]
```

**Another solution `List Comprehension`:**

```
In [403]: l = [{"start_date": str(ele), "end_date": str(x[ix + 1])} for ix, ele in enumerate(x) if ix + 1 < len(x)]

In [404]: if l[-1]['end_date'] < end_date:
     ...:     l.append({'start_date': l[-1]['end_date'], 'end_date':end_date})
     ...: 

In [405]: l
Out[405]: 
[{'start_date': '2021-10-01 17:30:00+00:00',
  'end_date': '2021-10-14 17:30:00+00:00'},
 {'start_date': '2021-10-14 17:30:00+00:00',
  'end_date': '2021-10-27 17:30:00+00:00'},
 {'start_date': '2021-10-27 17:30:00+00:00',
  'end_date': '2021-10-30T21:00:00Z'}]
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. Can you show me how I can add another start and end date to the remaining 

{
"start_date": "2021-10-27 17:30:00+00:00",
"end_date":"2021-10-30 17:30:00+00:00"
}

Comment: @pottttttossss Updated my answer. Please try now.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you basically what you want (assuming you want the final dates as strings):

```
import pandas as pd

start_date = '2021-10-01 17:30:00'
end_date = '2021-10-30 21:00:00'

dates = list(pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='13D').astype(str))
if dates[-1] != end_date:
    dates.append(end_date)

result = [{'start_date': start, 'end_date': end} for start, end in zip(dates, dates[1:])]
```

Comment: This is not returning the correct output. Please check.

Comment: You're right. Will fix in a moment.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd

start_date = '2021-10-01T17:30:00Z'
end_date = '2021-10-30T21:00:00Z'

s = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start_date, end_date ,freq='13D'), name='start_date')
e = s.shift(-1).rename('end_date')
df = pd.concat([s, e], axis=1).dropna(subset=['end_date']).astype('str')
df.to_dict('records')
```

```
>>>
[{'start_date': '2021-10-01 17:30:00+00:00',
  'end_date': '2021-10-14 17:30:00+00:00'},
 {'start_date': '2021-10-14 17:30:00+00:00',
  'end_date': '2021-10-27 17:30:00+00:00'}]
```